# I want to merge only one column from three tables and remaining column from three table should be display as usual

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables with columns

```
1. Amazon
   - Aapnik, Amazon
2. Jumbotail
   - Aapnik, Jumbotail
3. Udaan
   - Aapnik, Udaan
```

Now I want to join or merge Aapnik column from three tables and Display the remaining column as usual

```
**Amazon**             **Jumbotail**               **Udaan**          **Price**
Aapnik | Amazon        Aapnik | Jumbotail       Aapnik | Udaan    Aapnik | Price
-------+-------        -------+----------       -------+------    -------+------
   1   |   A              4   |   D                4   |   G         1   |  100
   2   |   B              2   |   E                6   |   H         2   |  500
   3   |   C              5   |   F                7   |   I         3   |  300
                                                                     4   |  200
                                                                     5   |  400
                                                                     6   |  250
                                                                     7   |  540
                                                                     8   |  760
                                                                     9   |  120
                                                                     10  |  230

**Amazonprice**       **Jumbotailprice**        **Udaanprice**
Aapnik | Amazon        Aapnik | Jumbotail       Aapnik | Udaan
-------+-------        -------+----------       -------+------
   A   |   140            D   |   220               G  |   230  
   B   |   580            E   |   520               H  |   101  
   C   |   320            F   |   490               I  |   333
   Q   |   270            P   |   562               W  |   456
```

This what I tried it combines all the aapnik column from the three tables but also it combines all the other three columns as one column

```
select aapnik, amazon from amazon union all
       select aapnik, jumbotail from jumbotail union all
        select aapnik, udaan from udaan;
```

This is what I want...

```
Aapnik | Amazon | Jumbotail | Udaan | Price | Amazonprice | Jumbotailprice | Udaanprice
-------+--------+-----------+-------+-------+-------------+----------------+------------
    1  |    A   |           |       |  100  |     140     |                |
    2  |    B   |     E     |       |  500  |     580     |       520      |
    3  |    C   |           |       |  300  |     320     |                |
    4  |        |     D     |   G   |  200  |             |       220      |    230
    5  |        |     F     |       |  400  |             |       490      |
    6  |        |           |   H   |  250  |             |                |    101
    7  |        |           |   I   |  540  |             |                |    333
```

Update:
How to get prices from the price table for this product?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Comment: You seem to be very hard to satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select p.Aapnik,a.Amazon, j.jumbotail, u.UdaanPrice from price p
left join Amazon a on p.Aapnik=a.Aapnik
left join jumbotail j on p.Aapnik=j.Aapnik
left join Udaan u on p.Aapnik=u.Aapnik
```

Comment: ERROR: column reference "aapnik_parent_sku" is ambiguous
  Position: 8

Comment: I have added new constraints, please have a look and help me to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

One method uses `union` to get all the `Aapnik` values and then `left join`:

```
select a.Aapnik, am.Amazon, jt.jumbotail, uu.uudon, p.price
from price p left join
     Amazon am
     on am.Aapnik = p.Aapnik left join
     jumbotail jt
     on jt.Aapnik = p.Aapnik left join
     Uudon uu
     on uu.Aapnik = p.Aapnik;
```

Comment: I have added new constraints, please have a look and help me to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

as full outer join is not avail in mysql so you could use left and right join and union

```
select aapnik, amazon from
 amazon a left join Jumbotail b
on a.Aapnik=b.Aapnik
union 
select Aapnik,Jumbotail
 amazon a right join Jumbotail b
on a.Aapnik=b.Aapnik
union 
select Aapnik,Jumbotail
 Jumbotail  a left join Udaan  b
on a.Aapnik=b.Aapnik
union 
select Aapnik,Udaan
 Jumbotail  a right join Udaan  b
on a.Aapnik=b.Aapnik
```

Comment: I have added new constraints, please have a look and help me to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

For your last update to the question, You can simply inner join the price table with the rest tables -

```
select a.Aapnik, am.Amazon, jt.jumbotail, ud.Udaan, p.Price
      ,ap.Amazon, jp.jumbotail, up.Udaan
from (select Aapnik from Amazon
      union
      select Aapnik from jumbotail
      union
      select Aapnik from Udaan ) a
join price p on a.Aapnik = p.Aapnik
left join Amazon am on am.Aapnik = a.Aapnik
left join Amazonprice ap on am.Amazon = ap.Aapnik
left join jumbotail jt on jt.Aapnik = a.Aapnik
left join Jumbotailprice jp on jt.jumbotail = jp.Aapnik
left join Udaan ud on ud.Aapnik = a.Aapnik
left join Udaanprice up on ud.Udaan=up.Aapnik
```

Comment: I have added new constraints, please have a look and help me to solve it...